Gitpod Configuration for running playwright with .net in a workspace
Following error message for every test.
Error Message:
   System.ArgumentException : Invalid browser name from 'BROWSER' environment variable.
Supported browsers: 'chromium', 'firefox', and 'webkit'
Actual browser: '/.supervisor/browser.sh'
Try to remove 'BROWSER' environment variable for using default browser
  Stack Trace:
     at Microsoft.Playwright.TestAdapter.PlaywrightSettingsProvider.ValidateBrowserName(String browserName, String fromText, String suffix) in /_/src/Playwright.TestAdapter/PlaywrightSettingsProvider.cs:line 102
   at Microsoft.Playwright.TestAdapter.PlaywrightSettingsProvider.get_BrowserName() in /_/src/Playwright.TestAdapter/PlaywrightSettingsProvider.cs:line 45
   at Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit.PlaywrightTest.PlaywrightSetup() in /_/src/Playwright.NUnit/PlaywrightTest.cs:line 44
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.TaskAwaitAdapter.GenericAdapter`1.GetResult()
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)

The tests should run seemlessly I have used gitpod but it seems the browser environment variable is wrong but I tried manually setting the System.environement.setenvironment but still the same error.
